# Regex; don't match numbers unless followed by '/'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: `{16}{2/W}{G/R}{W}`. I'm using javascript regex to extract the bracket contents, but I want to ignore any number-only brackets, like `{16}`. However, I want to match on brackets that have a number AND a letter, like `{2/W}`. So far I have `/{([^}0-9]+)}/g`, which matches `{G/R}` and `{W}` just fine, and excludes `{16}` as I want it to, but it doesn't match `{2/W}`. Is there a way of saying 'don't match numbers unless followed by non-numbers'?

Comment: Try this: `/{\d*?[a-zA-Z\/]+\d*?}/g`

Comment: have you tried escaping the `{` and `}`?

Comment: @Yuriy Yakym that only matches `{2/W}` and not `{W}` or `{G/R}`.

Comment: [Here you have an example](https://regex101.com/r/eJ8kO4/1)

Comment: @YuriyYakym apologies, I forgot the global flag. Your solution does indeed work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
var string = "{16}{2/W}{G/R}{W}";

var result = string.match(/{(\d*[^}\d]+[^}]*)}/g)

console.log(result);
```

This checks for 3 types of match:

- No digits at all (your original regex)
- Any leading digits, followed by at least one non-digit, and then anything but the closing '}'
- No leading digit, followed by any number of digits, and then anything but the closing '}'

Answer (score 1):

```js
var regExample = "{16}{2/W}{G/R}{W}";
var matches = regExample.match(/{([^}\d]+)\}|{(\d+\/\w+)}/g)
console.log(matches);
```